# Set indices of dataframe as a single key in dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I have a dataframe such as:

```
df = {'index': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,1,1,1,1, 2,2,2,2], 'value': ['val1', 'val2', 'val3', 'val4', 'val5', 'val6','val7','val8','val9','val10', 'val11','val12','val13','val14']}
```

I'd like to get a dictionary where each index would become a key in my dictionary, so that:
key=0 and values = ['val1', 'val2', 'val3', 'val4', 'val5']

Any idea how to do it? I've been using the 'to_dict' but it looks like I doesn't do what i need to do.

Answer (score 2):

I can think of something like:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'index': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,1,1,1,1, 2,2,2,2], 'value': ['val1', 'val2', 'val3', 'val4', 'val5', 'val6','val7','val8','val9','val10', 'val11','val12','val13','val14']})
df.groupby(by='index').apply(lambda x: list(x['value'])).to_dict()
```

Output is:

```
{0: ['val1', 'val2', 'val3', 'val4', 'val5'],
 1: ['val6', 'val7', 'val8', 'val9', 'val10'],
 2: ['val11', 'val12', 'val13', 'val14']}
```

Comment: thank you. I'd like to now dump this into a json file but my keys are now interpreted as ints and need to be strings. How can I do?

Comment: you can do `import json` and then `json.dumps(var1)`. should be something like `'{"0": ["val1", "val2", "val3", "val4", "val5"], "1": ["val6", "val7", "val8", "val9", "val10"], "2": ["val11", "val12", "val13", "val14"]}'`

Answer (score 2):

Use `groupby` and `apply`, followed by a final `to_dict` call.

```
df.groupby('index').value.apply(list).to_dict()
# {0: ['val1', 'val2', 'val3', 'val4', 'val5'],
#  1: ['val6', 'val7', 'val8', 'val9', 'val10'],
#  2: ['val11', 'val12', 'val13', 'val14']}
```

---

Another option is to iterate over your rows and append to values in a dictionary using `setdefault`.

```
d = {}
for k, v in zip(df['index'], df.value):
    d.setdefault(k, []).append(v)

print(d)
# {0: ['val1', 'val2', 'val3', 'val4', 'val5'],
#  1: ['val6', 'val7', 'val8', 'val9', 'val10'],
#  2: ['val11', 'val12', 'val13', 'val14']}
```

My tests indicate that this is actually performant than `groupby` for moderately sized frames. This will also preserve value ordering, while `groupby` performs a sort (whether it is stable or not is an implementation detail).

Comment: find a alt :-)~

Answer (score 1):

Using `itertools`

```
import itertools
l=df.sort_values('index').values.tolist()
d={k: [x[1] for x in g] for k, g in itertools.groupby(l,lambda x : x[0])}
d
{0: ['val1', 'val2', 'val3', 'val4', 'val5'], 1: ['val6', 'val7', 'val8', 'val9', 'val10'], 2: ['val11', 'val12', 'val13', 'val14']}
```